# Car will turnover, but not start

Tags: electrical, car, mitsubishi

I Have 97 Mitsubishi 3000gt. I am having problems starting the car. It will turnover, but occasionally not start. I will have then have to wait about an hour before i can confidently start the car without a problem. thoughts about what the problem could be?

Comment: Did you check your battery. Check whether it is charged or not. And check the alternator too.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I checked. The battery is fine.

Comment: my car does not stall or die, once I have started it. So, I do not think it is the altinator

Comment: Welcome and thanks for jumping in with an answer, since this is more of a clarifying question it should probably be a comment however.

Comment: When you are in a "no start" condition if you turn the key to "on" can hear the fuel pump run for approx. 5 seconds. You may need a helper to hear the noise as it will be near the fuel tank.

Comment: Do you hear a jeeer jeeeeeer sound when the car does not start? Or the starter sound is quite normal?

Answer (score 1):

A car engine needs air, fuel and spark in the right amount and right timing to work correctly.  Your car is likely fuel injected with an engine control computer with OnBoardDiagnostics (OBD2) communications.

There could be a whole bunch of things that causes this trouble.

Generally the engine control computer will provide feedback on potential issues, particularly involving fuel and emissions related issues.  With that said, first step is to read the stored codes in the computer and report back here.  Generally the system records any codes (including intermittent codes) from the last fifty starts.

I will say, the engine computer won't catch everything.  It may well miss anything that is spark (ignition) related.  It may not catch a vacuum leak.

My guess, based on the age of your car would be possibly  1) vacuum / emission related :

- Vacuum hose old, broken, leaking somewhere.
- An Exhaust Gas Recirculation (EGR) system failure somewhere, generally with a plugged up control valve.

or more likely 2) an ignition problem:

- burnt wire shorting out somewhere.  I'd like you to remove each wire from the spark plug, inspect for burnt or worn areas.  I'm assuming you have a common ignition module, and large diameter spark plug wires running to each plug.
- bad spark plugs.
- bad ignition module

To troubleshoot: 
1) read the codes on the OBD2 system.
2) Check all vacuum hoses.
3) Check for the correct functioning of the EGR system.
4) Check all spark plug wires.
5) Check spark plugs.

Best recommendation: Purchase a Chilton or Haynes Repair manual. They will guide  you in performing these tests.  $30 well spent.

By the way, how many miles are on this car?  What's your expected life for the car? If super high mileage (180,000 or more), you could have other engine troubles...

Comment: That was helpful... I have 140,000 miles on the car. A cold air intake was installed on my car prior to me buying it, but I will check the vacuum hoses regardless. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Along with what zipzit said, I'll just throw this out there:

I am having a similar problem with my car at the moment. In my case this is due to the fuel pump relay being on its last legs. Sometimes, when starting, the relay doesn't turn the fuel pump 'on' so the engine receives no fuel and just turns over without catching (no sputtering or coughing).

In my case simply pulling out the relay and pushing it back in seems to work in the short term (don't know why). Check if the relay is hot after running. It should be cheap to replace, but keep in mind a faulty relay could also be due to a dying fuel pump.

Answer (score 0):

You should also use a multimeter to do a voltage drop test. Sometimes the heavy cable between the battery and the starter starts going bad and prevents enough current ( amperage ) from reaching the starter.

There is a great video which explains this by [Schrodinger's Box on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfLyh43iihM).